# SQL returning specific value if a condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dates 
(
  dates DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO dates(dates)
VALUES
('2021-04-22 00:00:00.000'),
('2021-04-23 00:00:00.000'),
('2021-04-24 00:00:00.000')

CREATE TABLE deliveries 
(
  delivery_id VARCHAR(20),
  product VARCHAR(10),
  start_date DATETIME,
  end_date DATETIME,
);
INSERT INTO deliveries(delivery_id, product, start_date, end_date)
VALUES
('A01', 'CUSTOM', '2021-04-22', '2021-04-23'),
('A02', 'CUSTOM', '2021-04-21', '2021-04-22'),
('A03', 'NORMAL', '2021-04-01', '2021-04-30'),
('A04', 'NORMAL', '2021-04-22', '2021-04-24'),
('A05', 'NORMAL', '2021-04-19', '2021-04-22'),
('A06', 'NORMAL', '2021-04-20', '2021-04-20')
```

and this is my query:

```
declare @TodaysDate    datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) + '00:00:00.000'
declare @EndDate      datetime = dateadd(day,5,@TodaysDate)
declare @TomorrowsDate      datetime = dateadd(day,1,@TodaysDate)

select dt.dates, de.delivery_id, de.product 

from dates dt left join deliveries de
on dt.dates between de.start_date and de.end_date

and not(de.end_date = @TodaysDate AND de.product LIKE '%CUSTOM%')

order by delivery_id
```

Here is the result:

```
dates                   delivery_id   product
2021-04-22T00:00:00Z    A01           CUSTOM
2021-04-23T00:00:00Z    A01           CUSTOM
2021-04-23T00:00:00Z    A03           NORMAL
2021-04-24T00:00:00Z    A03           NORMAL
2021-04-22T00:00:00Z    A03           NORMAL
2021-04-22T00:00:00Z    A04           NORMAL
2021-04-24T00:00:00Z    A04           NORMAL
2021-04-23T00:00:00Z    A04           NORMAL
2021-04-22T00:00:00Z    A05           NORMAL
```

I need to amend this query to add one more condition to only return rows with `end_date` (but not `start_date`) in `dates` column when product is `CUSTOM` and `start_date` is today (2021-04-22) and `end_date` is tomorrow (2021-04-23). So in the above case, the result should not include `2021-04-22 | A01` row but start from the 2nd row: `2021-04-23 | A01`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add below condition in where clause:

```
 and not ( start_date = @TodaysDate and end_date =@TomorrowsDate AND de.product LIKE '%CUSTOM%'
 and dates=start_date)
```

DB-Fiddle:

```
 CREATE TABLE dates 
 (
   dates DATETIME
 );
 INSERT INTO dates(dates)
 VALUES
 ('2021-04-22 00:00:00.000'),
 ('2021-04-23 00:00:00.000'),
 ('2021-04-24 00:00:00.000')
 
 CREATE TABLE deliveries 
 (
   delivery_id VARCHAR(20),
   product VARCHAR(10),
   start_date DATETIME,
   end_date DATETIME,
 );
 INSERT INTO deliveries(delivery_id, product, start_date, end_date)
 VALUES
 ('A01', 'CUSTOM', '2021-04-22', '2021-04-23'),
 ('A02', 'CUSTOM', '2021-04-21', '2021-04-22'),
 ('A03', 'NORMAL', '2021-04-01', '2021-04-30'),
 ('A04', 'NORMAL', '2021-04-22', '2021-04-24'),
 ('A05', 'NORMAL', '2021-04-19', '2021-04-22'),
 ('A06', 'NORMAL', '2021-04-20', '2021-04-20')
 GO
```

Query:

```
 declare @TodaysDate    datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) + '00:00:00.000'
 declare @EndDate      datetime = dateadd(day,5,@TodaysDate)
 declare @TomorrowsDate      datetime = dateadd(day,1,@TodaysDate)
 
 select dt.dates, de.delivery_id, de.product 
 
 from dates dt left join deliveries de
 on dt.dates between de.start_date and de.end_date
 
 and not(de.end_date = @TodaysDate AND de.product LIKE '%CUSTOM%')
 and not ( start_date = @TodaysDate and end_date =@TomorrowsDate AND de.product LIKE '%CUSTOM%'
 and dates=start_date)
 
 
 
 order by delivery_id
```

Output:

| dates | delivery_id | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-23 00:00:00.000 | A01 | CUSTOM |
| 2021-04-23 00:00:00.000 | A03 | NORMAL |
| 2021-04-22 00:00:00.000 | A03 | NORMAL |
| 2021-04-24 00:00:00.000 | A03 | NORMAL |
| 2021-04-24 00:00:00.000 | A04 | NORMAL |
| 2021-04-22 00:00:00.000 | A04 | NORMAL |
| 2021-04-23 00:00:00.000 | A04 | NORMAL |
| 2021-04-22 00:00:00.000 | A05 | NORMAL |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d0b2884df202baa57f471107791217f5)*

Comment: You are most welcome. You asked a perfect question with table structures, sample values, your attempt with result. You deserve an upvote for that. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your query to this and see if it gives you the right data:

```
select 
    dt.dates, 
    de.delivery_id, de.product 
from dates dt 
left join deliveries de on dt.dates between de.start_date and de.end_date
and not(de.end_date = @TodaysDate AND de.product LIKE '%CUSTOM%')
and not(de.product LIKE '%CUSTOM%' AND dt.dates = @TodaysDate AND de.end_date = @TomorrowsDate)
order by de.delivery_id
```